# Need to capture timeout case for JdbcTemplate.setQueryTimeout

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I've got a problem where a mysql server is hanging when I query to it sometimes, and sometimes it's completely down. I'm connecting to it using a spring JdbcTemplate. I saw JdbcTemplate has a setTimeout method, but I'm not sure how to check whether the timeout occurred. I'm calling it like this:

```
try {
    JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    template.setQueryTimeout(3);
    SqlRowSet rs = template.queryForRowSet(sql);

} catch (DataAccessException e) {
    String msg = "Can't connect to database.";
    response.addError(msg + " " + e);
    logger.error(msg, e);
    return response;
}
```

I know that this is working properly when the database is down but I'm not sure how to test whether the query was stopped as a result of the timeout, or if the query executed fine and no records were returned.

Adding to my problem is that I can't actually reproduce the condition in which the server is hanging right now so I can't experiment on my own. Is there a certain type of exception I should be checking for, or will a DataAccessException be thrown? Or possibly there's something I can check in the SqlRowSet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the documentation for [Statement.executeQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery-java.lang.String-) it does define a `SQLTimeoutException`. This will be thrown if a timeout is set and exceeded (with numerous conditions) - check your database driver's documentation.

Spring's jdbc template calls this internally and the java.sql exception is translated by spring's [SQLExceptionTranslator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/SQLExceptionTranslator.html) into a [QueryTimeoutException](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/QueryTimeoutException.html)

I would suggest catching this exception.

Comment: It looks like QueryTimeoutException extends DataAccessException so I don't need to do anything else. Thanks!